# Find the average of pairs with the same first element in FME

Tags: python, fme-form, list, average

I have a list of pairs in FME:

[image] [image]

and need to calculate the average of each set of pairs with the same first element.

I came up with this code, but it takes a lot of time to paste and copy the list. Is there any method in FME can do the same thing as the Python code. Or is there any other way I can improve my Python code?

```
mylist=[[[13,13],[22,4],[14,4],[19,4],[12,0],[21,223],[18,5],[16,0],[21,0],[6,4],[10,7],[19,1],[16,0],[7,0],[6,4],[23,2],\
[13,0],[19,3],[5,40],[9,0],[21,1],[8,316],[22,3],[12,304],[12,0],[22,2],[11,258],[21,0],[16,0],[5,0],[0,4],[0,0],\
[15,10],[17,439],[3,0],[15,394],[7,0],[21,172],[0,0],[6,9],[21,151],[0,0],[17,442],[2,10],[0,0],[11,19],[14,5],\
[11,19],[17,377],[8,304],[7,11],[11,282],[3,1],[5,3],[7,262],[13,6],[11,295],[21,11],[4,30],[4,1],[4,0],[8,11],\
[7,244],[2,0],[7,3],[0,1],[15,384],[8,25],[20,242],[4,0],[15,11],[12,12],[5,0],[8,287],[21,2],[4,0],[4,0],[18,6],\
[12,14],[15,12],[21,3],[19,4],[5,3],[19,7],[13,5],[18,4],[13,6],[7,2],[22,1],[11,244],[16,4],[17,465],[11,290],\
[10,10],[8,14],[6,5],[23,2],[19,2],[23,0],[16,2]]
from collections import defaultdict
mydict=defaultdict(list)
for hour,value in mylist:
   mydict[(hour)].append(value)
print (mydict)
lst=[]
for (hour), values in mydict.items():
   lst.append((hour,sum(values)/len(values)))
lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're trying to do? This is almost certainly easier to do with your list before you concatenate it. From what I understand, you would like to average the values of the pairs only if the first number is the same? Perhaps a StatisticsCalculator with a group by attribute? So, if you had the values [7,2],[7,3],[7,4],[8,3],[8,5] then the average would be `(7+2+7+3+7+4)/3` and `(8+3+8+5)/2`? Is that how you'd like to calculate it?

Comment: Alternatively, can you just embed your working python code into a PythonCaller transformer and pass in the string? You wouldn't have to copy/paste.